# Bootstrap fixed menu + jquery dialog issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-dialog

When I show JQuery dialog in small window, it placed to the top of page and menu closes the dialog.

```
$(function () {
    $('.d').dialog({
                width: '75%',
                height: 600,
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
        position: [ "center", 100]
    });
});
```

See: http://snag.gy/BSJVs.jpg

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ishubin/9ruhx/1/

How can I fix it (for example set margin-top: 100px)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two easy ways of dealing with this problem.

The cleaner solution: Make sure that if the dialog box is displayed, it is always on top of the menu:

```
// add this to your css file

div.ui-dialog {
     z-index: 1031 !important;   
}
```

a working example can be found on http://jsfiddle.net/9ruhx/2/.

Otherwise, you can make sure that the dialog always opens just below the menu at the top:

```
// your css file

div.ui-dialog {
     top: 45px !important;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/9ruhx/3/.

Comment: This solution applied for a conflict I was having as well. Because I had a modal dialog, I needed to set div.ui-widget-overlay to a z-index of 1030 so the overlay screen was at the right z-level.